# Android Studio doesn't generate Drawable from VectorDrawable for old versions

Tags: android, android-studio, android-vectordrawable

I use Android Studio 2.0 and support `VectorDrawable` library.
My gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }
}
```

But when I try to load icon in menu on old device:

```
MenuItem miSubjects = menu.add(R.id.menu_navigation, ACTION_SUBJECTS_ID, order, R.string.action_subjects);
miSubjects.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_labels_gray_24dp));
```

Icon is a vector but AndroidStudio must generate and drawable for old versions (raster drawable). If it isn't so when how I need to use it?

Vector example `ic_labels_gray_24dp.xml`

```
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#8a000000"
        android:pathData="m15.316,4.5 l-10.316,0.008c-1.169,-0 -2,0.96 -2,2v5.984c0,1.043 0.78,2 2,2l10.316,0.008c0.991,0 0.968,0.014 1.543,-0.6l4.141,-4.4 -4.141,-4.4c-0.594,-0.594 -0.552,-0.6 -1.543,-0.6zM20.019,13.459 L18.316,15.269c-0.284,0.303 -0.614,0.743 -1.354,1.027 -0.741,0.285 -1.161,0.203 -1.646,0.203h-0.002l-10.316,-0.008c-0.74,0 -1.413,-0.225 -1.998,-0.578v1.578c0,1.043 0.78,2 2,2l10.316,0.008c0.991,0 0.968,0.014 1.543,-0.6l4.141,-4.4 -0.98,-1.041z"/>
</vector>
```

**P.S.** It wrote a simple class. It doesn't fix Android Studio bug but at least app will not crash. Maybe someone else has same problem.

```
public final class VectorDrawable {

    private VectorDrawable() {}

    public static Drawable getDrawable(Context context, final int id) {
        return VectorDrawableCompat.create(context.getResources(), id, context.getTheme());
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem with vector drawables, did you figure out a solution?

Comment: At this moment I became use `ContextCompat.getDrawable()` and it became work. Although in old versions of the Support Library it doesn't work for `VectorDrawable` on device with API level lower 20.